# Zapier: How to post tweets from trello multiple attachments of images?

Tags: twitter, zapier, trello

I am using a zapier zap to post tweet from trello card added to a specific list.
The description part goes to tweet text and attachment image goes to image of tweet.
In case of one image attachment works well. I use zapier formatter to extract an image url from trello card's attachment.
But I want to tweet more than 1 images. In that case zapier pass the multiple attachments as one zipped file contains attached images. So it fails to pass it to the twitter as invalid media format because it is zipped format but not image format just like .jpg, or .png.

How can I implement this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is expected behavior in how the hydration process is handled for multiple images.

You might be able to use a third-party service like - https://zapier.com/apps/convertapi/integrations  app to get these files unzipped within the editor.

With that said, afaik, unless you're creating your own private dev Twitter app, the main app only able to accept one image per post at the moment.